# How to sort list items in specific sub-folder of the list after creation of new item?

Tags: workflow, folder, list-item, save

I have a list with information (news). There are severel sub-folders in the list, and according to the content, a new list item shall be put in one of those sub-folders.

If a new item is created in the list, how can I make sure that it is saved to the right sub-folder immediately?
Can I use a workflow to ask the user, in which sub-folder it belongs?

In the above mentioned case, the sub-folders are predefined and will not change often. (However, in general it would also be interesting if there is a dynamic solution which could take into account the currently available folders)

Comment: Are the folder going to change often? Can users add folders?

Comment: no, the folders would be "static"

Comment: Is the concern that users will unwittingly use the wrong folder, or that they might not know which folder the document belongs in?

Comment: both - folders shall define permissions. Not many users will have the permissions to create those items, but many users will set an alert on this list and get notified about changes. And if the item would be in the wrong folder, the wrong people would get notified (who have not the right to see it)

Answer (score 1):

Since the folders will be mostly static, you could add a dropdown with all the folder names and require that users the select the correct folder. Then with a workflow, if the folder they put it in doesn't match the dropdown selection, copy the file into the dropdown folder and delete the original.

Though I really think, on principle, if the number of people with permissions to create is small, that intensive training for those few people to make them understand the importance of selecting the correct folder would be the better approach. I try to avoid building extra functionality on top of OOTB functions in lieu of enforcing processes.

Comment: If you decide you need the dropdown, and you want to populate it dynamically, I would use SPServices or JSOM.